# Debugging on Microsoft Windows Platforms

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I try to debug c in Visual Studio 2010 from running matlab 2010.

Because the result is not right. ([How to write the mexFunction of this c file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520475/how-to-write-the-mexfunction-of-this-c-file))

```
        a= randn(num_of_dir,1);
        b = randn(num_of_dir,1);
        c =  randn(num_of_dir,1);
        ru =  1;
        ld=3;
        htemp= randn(num_of_dir,1);;
        x = mexFunction(a,b,c, ld, ru,htemp,num_of_dir);
```

I did some steps as the instruction from
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html

Unfortunately, it does not stop at Visual Studio 2010? Could anyone give me some suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate to the line of code where you need to stop and press F9. It places a breakpoint in that line.